# Toggle Window Decorations

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, window

For screencasting purposes I would like to be able to easily toggle window decorations - primarily the titlebar at the top of applications - on and off. I can't find an easy way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04 as the ccsm plugin "Decoration Windows" conflicts with the Unity plugin. If it were possible to construct a keyboard shortcut to toggle this, that would be particularly desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the incompatibility with CCSM and Unity, there might be a way to remove the top titlebar in Unity using [Themes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming).

You could bind a script ([example](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2048022)) to enable/disable the theming. The script - instead of killing/restarting the theme process as in the example - could replace the CSS files used for theming to change the activation of the title bar.